Postgresql select values sum from same ID and add new column
this is my table called "plan"



Plan No.
Weight




T190234
21


T190234
14


T190234
35


T190245
100


T190245
80


T190339
12


T190339
45


T190339
33



This should be my expected result: sum of column "totalwight"



Plan No.
Weight
totalwight




T190234
21
70


T190234
14
70


T190234
35
70


T190245
100
180


T190245
80
180


T190339
12
80


T190339
45
80


T190339
33
80




Use a windows function to achieve this...
select 
 plan_no, 
 weight, 
 sum(weight) over (partition by plan_no) as total_weight
from plan




plan_no
weight
total_weight




T190234
21
70


T190234
14
70


T190234
35
70


T190245
100
180


T190245
80
180


T190339
12
90


T190339
45
90


T190339
33
90



fiddle
